# Powershell Executable Package Stops after first script

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of powershell scripts that I want to run.  All scripts reside in the same directory and I have one script that works through and calls the other scripts.  I've tried to use a couple of "Packaging" tools (e.g. Powershell Pro Packager).  It generates the package successfully, but when I attempt to run the exe, it prints the output of the first script it calls and then stops.  No errors or anything.  When I run directly in the terminal, it goes through and calls each script as expected.  Does anyone have any idea why it behaves this way?

This is what the main package looks like:

```
param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory)]
     [int]$CompanyId,
     [Parameter(Mandatory)]
     [int]$CleanupEnabled
)

#Get configuration settings 
try{
$configsettings = .\sftpSettings.ps1 -CompanyId $CompanyId
}

catch{
    Write-Host "Error:" $_
}

#Call the File Transfer process and pass parameters that process needs.
write-host "Initiating File Transfer"
try{
$syncfiles = .\sftpFileDownload.ps1 -CompanyId $CompanyId -localDir $configsettings.localDownloadDir -sftphost $configsettings.sftpHost -port $configsettings.sftpPort -un $configsettings.sftpUn -pw $configsettings.sftpPw -sftpfingerprint $configsettings.sftpHostFingerprint -deleteremote $configsettings.deleteAfterDownload -sftpDownloadDir $configsettings.sftpHostDownloadDir
}

catch{
    Write-Host "Error:" $_
}
```

Comment: I think we're going to need some more info, this script only calls two other scripts it doesn't look like there's any issue with it. When you create the packager does it keep all the scripts inside the executable? Maybe only the first script is getting included? If there's a config you use for generating this package then that would be good to see as well.

Comment: An exception is only captured once unless the exception handler has a throw so another exception handler can report the error.  You need to debug the sftpSettings and sftpFiledownload scripts to find out why code is stopping.  It may have an exception or just stopping because the logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue by converting each of the child scripts into a PS module instead of just another script.  I'm not sure if it's just a product of the tool we were using to convert to an executable or if any tool that does this would do the same, but the issue was related to it not waiting for the preceeding script to complete/return results before going on to the next script.  Since the child scripts depend on data returned from the previous script(s), the parameters were being passed in as nulls.